# how to increment the conuter in project block in mongoid using $cond keyword in rails

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Am new to MongoID

i need to increment the counter in project using $cond keyword

```
 lists = TableName.collection.aggregate({"$match" => {"starttime"=> { "$gte" => u},"_mac_id" => {"$in" => mac_ids.uniq} }}, {"$project"=>{"stayedtime"=>1, "rl_mac_id"=>1, "vd_mac_id"=>1, "con"=> {"$cond"=> [ { "$gte"=> [ "$stayedtime", 300 ] }, "then"=> { "$sum" => 1 } , "else"=> { "$sum" => 1 } ]  }}},{"$group"=>{"_id"=>"$rl_mac_id","c"=>"$con", "visits"=> { "$sum" => 1 }, "tust"=>{"$sum"=>"$stayedtime"}, "visitors"=> { "$addToSet" => "$vd_mac_id"}}})
```

but its not working.. its giving error. I know there is no "$sum"  keyword in project. But instead of that is there any thing.

Advance thanks..

Comment: use `$add:["$value",1]`, `$sum` is a `$group` accumulator operator. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/